# JVM bytecode jump instructions

Tags: bytecode, goto

How does JVM ensure that jump instructions (`jsr` and `goto`) jump to the instruction and not data or instruction arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the bytecode verifier.

In Java bytecode, instructions all have a known length and must appear one after another starting at offset 0, so you can always tell statically where the beginning of each instruction is. Therefore, it's just a simple matter of making sure the jump target is the beginning of a valid instruction. Unlike with Dalvik or x86, you aren't allowed to jump into the middle of an instruction.

[You can find the source code for the verifier here.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/common/check_code.c) Actually there are two verifiers. This is the classic verfier, used for code which doesn't have a StackMapTable (this includes all code containing `jsr`).